# Can't seem to implement a one to zero to one relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue where I can't seem to implement even a one to one relationship, much less a one to zero or one relationship in my classes MySQL web server.

I have a list of individuals that can be a volunteer, and a volunteer has to be listed as an individual. It should have an optional on attached to the volunteers table and mandatory one to the individuals table. My current code seems to be implementing as a one to zero:many relationship in the reverse engineered ERD.

Here is a picture of the reverse engineered model:

[image]

Here is my current code (I added the unique constraint on individual_id to try to force at least a one to one):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `individuals` (
  `individual_id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  , `first_name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
  , `last_name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
  , `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , `street` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
  , `city` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  , `state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL
  , `zipcode` CHAR(5) NOT NULL
  , `privacy_flag` INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `volunteers` (
  `volunteer_id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  , `volunteer_type` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
  , `individual_id` INTEGER NOT NULL
  , UNIQUE KEY `indiv_id` (`individual_id`) 
  , CONSTRAINT `vol_fk1` FOREIGN KEY `indiv_id` (`individual_id`) REFERENCES `individuals` (`individual_id`)
);
```

Comment: The unique constraint should do what you want. What's the problem?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm starting to think it may be an issue with the way the web server is rendering the ERD. I even tried building the ERD and reverse engineering the SQL to drop that in and it didn't work. Asking here to make sure I'm not missing something or have some improper syntax

Comment: MySQL doesn't have explicit notations for different kinds of relationships. The tool for creating the ERD may not be able to recognize that the unique constraint applies to the foreign key. But the code should work as desired.

Comment: The relation "one to one" cannot be implemented in MySQL. The reason is simple - there is no statement in MySQL which inserts rows in two tables at the same time.

But you can easily implement the relation "one to zero/one". In "main" table the relational column is defined as PRIMARY KEY or as UNIQUE and NOT NULL. In "slave" table it is defined as PRIMARY KEY (or as UNIQUE and NOT NULL) and FOREIGN KEY to "main" table. Your code matches this completely (and separate PK presence in `volunteers` seems to be excess).

Comment: It's how Akina says: in MySQL the cardinality of the relationship can't be positive on both sides.